# Problem with setting JavaF ImageView image from URL

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, rapidapi

I build desktop app in JavaFX and Spring (net.rgielen). I use one of RapidAPI API. I am trying to display an image with a URL provided with this API (for example: https://tipsscore.com/resb/team/fiorentina.png), but it does not work. The image is not displayed. My piece of Java code:

```
@FXML
private ImageView homeTeamLogo;

...

String url = "https://tipsscore.com/resb/team/fiorentina.png";
Image image = new Image(url);
homeTeamLogo = new ImageView(image);
```

And a FXML element:

```
<fx:root prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="400.0" type="javafx.scene.control.ListCell" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <graphic>
            <AnchorPane>
                    <ImageView fx:id="homeTeamLogo" fitHeight="82.0" fitWidth="77.0" layoutX="33.0" layoutY="40.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
            </AnchorPane>
    </graphic>
</fx:root>
```

I tried this solution:
[JavaFX - image url not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55075985/javafx-image-url-not-loading)

but didn`t help.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Never set something annotated @FXML to a new value.

Comment: As noted, never reassign an `@FXML`-annotated field. Such fields are injected with the instance displayed in the UI by the `FXMLLoader`. If you reassign one then you lose access to that instance. You should probably be doing something like `homeTeamLogo.setImage(image)`.